# How to make the main ground generate infinity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, infinity

Hello I am a beginner in unity 3D and I want to create a game where a ball rolls on the ground and you need to doge the obstacles but I don't know how to create the ground generate infinity and I also want to do that when you move out of the view the ground which is not in the main cam disappears.

Comment: Possibly relevant _"endless runner"_ games in Unity 3D (no specific link).

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5hRtTEhnOA&list=PLZ1b66Z1KFKit4cSry_LWBisrSbVkEF4t&index=1

Comment: You can achieve this by destroying far away object and summoning new object in certain distance in front of the player